# What is the purpose of ios::adjustfield?

Tags: c++, stream, flags

What exactly is `ios::adjustfield` and what does it do? When and how would I go about making use of it?

Answer (score 1):

`ios::adjustfield` is a bit mask that is made by OR'ing together `ios::left`, `ios::right`, and `ios::internal`. The latter three are flags that control the adjustment of the output. [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) has a nice example of what those three flags do.

It doesn't make much sense to set `ios::adjustfield` itself, though - it doesn't make any sense to set more than one of the three adjust flags at any given time. So why does the standard library provide it?

The answer is to make it easy to *clear* existing adjust flags. If `flg` is the current set of formatting flags, you can't set `ios::right` simply by `flg |= ios::right;`, because if a different adjustment flag is already set, you just set two adjustment flags on at the same time, which is nonsensical.

Instead, you need to clear the current adjustment flags first with `flg &= ~ios::adjustfield;` This clears the way for you to then set another adjustment flag with `flg |= ios::right;` The function [`ios::setf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf), which manipulates the `ios` flags, allows you to give it a mask of flags to be cleared.

Note that you usually don't need to use `ios::adjustfield` directly; the I/O manipulators `std::left`, `std::right` and `std::internal` are far more convenient.